# Private API to get list of ringtones / sms tones

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, iphone-privateapi, ios8.1

I am trying to change the ring tone of a specific contact programatically. It says on multiple places in SO that this is not possible however I have came quite a long way.

So far I have retrieved the ABRecord for the person I want to change the ring tone on. I have also found out that the ring tones seem to be stored in ABRecord number 16 (not defined in any .h file I know of). I have manually prepared the contact by adding a ring tone for both text and voice, and also a vibration for text and voice.

The below code will rewrite the same ring tones to the contact and if I run it I will see no changes in the actual contact, the set ring tones remain.

```
CFTypeRef tones = ABRecordCopyValue(entry, 16);
NSLog(@"%@", tones);
tones = ABMultiValueCreateMutableCopy(tones);
NSLog(@"%@", tones);
ABRecordSetValue(entry, 16, tones, &error);
```

If I do this instead all ring tone info on the contact is removed in the address book app, although it seem that the values are actually set and remains like this even after app restart. Note that I write back the exact same stringvalues here:

```
CFTypeRef tones = ABRecordCopyValue(entry, 16);
NSLog(@"%@", tones);
tones = ABMultiValueCreateMutableCopy(tones);
NSLog(@"%@", tones);
ABRecordSetValue(entry, 16, tones, &error);

ABMutableMultiValueRef multiSmsTone = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABStringPropertyType);
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiSmsTone, (__bridge CFTypeRef)@"<default>", NULL, NULL);
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiSmsTone, (__bridge CFTypeRef)@"Alert", NULL, NULL);
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiSmsTone, (__bridge CFTypeRef)@"<none>", NULL, NULL);
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiSmsTone, (__bridge CFTypeRef)@"Alert", NULL, NULL);
ABRecordSetValue(entry, 16, multiSmsTone, &error);
```

This is the output on the console and the error variable is always null:

```
2014-12-18 11:24:02.972 App[2992:1897663] ABMultiValueRef 0x170268f40 with 4 value(s)
    0: null (0x19976aba0) - <default> (0x170234420)
    1: null (0x19976aba0) - Alert (0x170234400)
    2: null (0x19976aba0) - <none> (0x1702343e0)
    3: null (0x19976aba0) - Alert (0x1702343c0)
2014-12-18 11:24:02.974 App[2992:1897663] ABMultiValueRef 0x170269000 with 4 value(s)
    0: null (0x19976aba0) - <default> (0x170234420)
    1: null (0x19976aba0) - Alert (0x170234400)
    2: null (0x19976aba0) - <none> (0x1702343e0)
    3: null (0x19976aba0) - Alert (0x1702343c0)
2014-12-18 11:24:04.609 App[2992:1897663] ABMultiValueRef 0x174260280 with 4 value(s)
    0: null (0x19976aba0) - <default> (0x1000ace70)
    1: null (0x19976aba0) - Alert (0x1000ace90)
    2: null (0x19976aba0) - <none> (0x1000aceb0)
    3: null (0x19976aba0) - Alert (0x1000ace90)
```

The only thing I can think of here is that the memory addresses of the string literals seem to be constant in the first and second NSLog however in the third they are all different. Also the first values seem to be different between app restarts.

Does this sound reasonable? Any idea where I could get the correct string literals in that case?
I need to set the contact's sms tone to "<none>".

**EDIT:** It seem like if there is something called identifier for a ABMultiValue. The identifiers for the above objects are -2, -102, -1, -101, I can get them using ABMultiValueGetIdentifierAtIndex(tones, 0) where 0 is the index from 0-3. When I create my own multi value with ABMultiValueCreateMutable I get completely different identifiers. Now I guess I just need some kind of hack to change the identifier of the multivalues.

Comment: I am not sure if you are even allowed to do so. Please check the App Store Guidelines.

Comment: @salocinx Please note that this is a request for private APIs == not for app store release. App store guidelines is therefore irrelevant.

Comment: Okay sorry, I just wanted to save your time ;-) Not that you're building something that you can't publish when finished. But I unfortunately can't help you - wish you good luck!